# Check which languages an application supports programmatically

Tags: android, multilingual

Is it possible to check programmatically which languages an application supports, by support I mean has a values-xx\strings.xml in its project?

Or even specifically my application....

(I know that I should know before hand which, but these things change, and would like not to maintain this manually)

Thanks.

Comment: Please define "supports".

Comment: by support I mean has a values-xx\strings.xml in its project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up adding an Enum with the values which are supported... I wanted to avoid that for the sake of generalizing, but it seems I cannot!